# Zend Lucene delete document

Tags: zend-framework, search, lucene, zend-lucene

I have question about delete document in index file.

I have this:

```
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open('data/index');
foreach ($index->find('pk:' . $this->getId()) as $hit) {
        $index->delete($hit->id);
    }
$index->commit();
```

And I use **[Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) (It can open index file)**

So before delete I see in my index entry. And after delete this entry still exist in index file, but in folder I see file for example _c0_del. So if this is normal, that after delete I can see my entry in index file? Or there is some error in my code? I try make

```
 var_dump($segmentInfo->delete($id - $segmentStartId));
```

In  **ZendSearch / library / ZendSearch / Lucene / Index.php** in delete method. And it give me null. Is it normal? If delete method physical remove document from index or just set flag that this document isDeleted? I use lucene maybe 2 years ago, and It physical remove document from index file. So after delete I can't see my entry in index through Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Luke does not show your deleted document, then even if the document is still in the index it will not matter -- the deleted document has been removed from consideration by the Lucene search engine and will be physically removed later in the indexing process.